# How to merge this PHP script to make one error message?

Tags: php, merge, submit, recaptcha

I am trying to merge multiple strings although it just seems to throw an error.

```
// Regex Tests
$error_message = "";

// Expressions
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($email_exp, $email_from)) {
    $error_message + 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp, $first_name)) {
    $error_message + 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp, $last_name)) {
    $error_message + 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!empty($error_message)) {
    formError($error_message);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this:

```
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
 }
```

Put this:

```
require_once('php/recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "enter private key";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    $error_message .= 'The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.<br />';
}
```

Comment: Did you remove the reCAPTCHA code from where it was originally? Show me the modified source code.

Comment: Yeah before it was at the very top in PHP tags and then I moved ti exactly where you told me to